# Worried I've commited shirk!

Tags: sin, shirk, forgiveness

I'm 13 years old, and a girl.

Ever since I had persisted in a small sin, I started to realised that I may have committed a major sin!
I became so worried, I started to cry, I panicked and I desperately spoke to Allah and I promised him that one day I would learn how to pray and perform tabwah. I felt like Allah wouldn't be there to forgive me and I felt so disgusted in myself. I sincerely regret my actions.

I soon learnt that Allah would forgive all sins and my faith was restored and I felt confident again. I then decided to research the major sins and I learnt about 'Shirk'. When I understood what it meant, I started thinking horrible things such as 'I worship another god along with Allah' but i didn't really mean it. I thought to myself that if I really committed shirk I would've put my heart and soul into worshipping the other god and I always reminded myself that it is only Allah that I worship, and nobody else.

When I started to think this, I became so worried, I panicked once again and researched if Allah would forgive Shirk. A few said that they wouldn't forgive Shirk unless they repented. I heard that Allah forgives ALL sins, and some said Allah wouldn't forgive Shirk.

Please answer my question as I do not want to suffer in stress any longer. I'm crying as I am writing this please, please, please! I do not want to go to hell and I fear greatly of it!! :(

Answer (score 0):

no you didnt commit Shirk; shirk is the actual belief that their is other Gods beside allah, even persisting on a sin while acknowledging it is a sin is not at all Shirk.

If you denied that a sin is a sin, and called it halal, even after been presented and acknowledged and understood the evidence that it is indeed a sin, then and only then it would be considered shirk; not because of the persistence but because in your heart you denied something that Allah said it is a sin and called it halal.

and always remember this hadith

Abu Huraira reported Allah's Messenger (may peace be upon him) having said: By Him in Whose Hand is my life, if you were not to commit sin, Allah would sweep you out of existence and He would replace (you by) those people who would commit sin and seek forgiveness from Allah, and He would have pardoned them.

http://qaalarasulallah.com/hadithView.php?ID=17032

even if we are weak and still commit sins, Allah wants to show us his grace and mercy as long we acknowledge our mistakes and understand them and work on not repeating them,

Answer (score 0):

Sister,
You are a lady of eeman.these whispers of shaitaan come to those who have eeman in their hearts.What would sayan do with a ruined house.
He surely is after a treasure and this treasure is your eeman.
You havent done shirk just ignore these thoughts